# If I'm integrating two seperate API's, is a MERN stack appropriate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, integration, mern

I have two separate cloud-based APIs that I am working on integrating together. Neither software directly talks to each other so I am creating something in the middle to get them to communicate. I have had trouble finding examples or documentation on how exactly to do this, does anyone know of any resources that could help me out?

My plan going in was to use a MERN Stack, running on a local server to do GET and POST requests to both APIs, use some mapping and logic to transpose the data into the correct format and send it to the other software. I do not have a client per se (other than myself) on my end, so I really will be skipping the React part of MERN, at least that is what I'm thinking. I'll be using Mongo to keep track of both sets of data for redundancy. I also considered using a LAMP Stack but felt that MERN would be faster in handling the data, and Mongo is more flexible in handling different data formats. If there is another process or technology that could help me that I'm not thinking of, I would be grateful to hear about it.

Has anyone encountered something like this before? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As with most architecture questions, there's no completely right or wrong answer here. You could certainly design a well-built system to handle for this purpose with either stack; even more-so when you mention that your front-end framework is not an important consideration. Instead, ask yourself questions like this:

**Which stack do you have more experience with, and is this an appropriate time to learn a new set of technologies, or is it important to do the best work you're capable of right now (how important is time, cost, or quality in this case)?**

Another generalization I'll stick my neck out for is a data-first approach; **what sort of data are you dealing with from each cloud integration, and what kind of data do you need to support and/or create in order to make your system work?** Mongo, being a NoSQL persistence layer, will allow you to change your data model and handle more varied data in a quicker and easier manner than a SQL solution will. This is a double-edged sword, however, as lack of validation and a strongly-constrained (typed?) data model will make your application harder to work with and debug as it grows. In short - how big might this application grow?

If you have a handy and familiar way to manage the three different data models you're dealing with (cloud service 1, cloud service 2, and your app) via MySQL, then that's a compelling reason to use it. However, if your style is to start dumping data into your database and you're comfortable with a more iterative approach (which may require more, albeit shorter rounds of refactoring), then Mongo with MERN may be the preferable choice.

Finally, will others ever be working on this application? If so, which language would you prefer to be dealing with them upon - PHP or Javascript?

Comment: Thank you. That is very good information and I'll definitely consider all of it as I finish up mapping everything out.

One sends in XML but has a built in Node.JS SDK to send the data in a JSON format, and the other accepts JSON as well. I feel most comfortable with Javascript and feel like going with that. I appreciate your feedback, thank you.